# No RuleTable cells in spreadsheet - Excel File and DRT

Tags: java, excel, spring, drools

I got issue with my integration to drools. I am using spring-boot-drool-starter which can be found here: https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-starter-drools. I am decide to use this library, because kmodule.xml declared paths, doesn't search in spring boot's BOOT-INF...

What I am facing currently is Caused by: org.drools.template.parser.DecisionTableParseException: No RuleTable cells in spreadsheet.

I am assuming that there is problem with merging the .drt file (which includes the rules) and .xls. 
This is how my structure looks. Do you have any ideas? I am fighting with research and issue around the week...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use *kmodule.xml* file to merge spreadsheet with drt template. You can do it using *ExternalSpreadsheetCompiler* which generates DRL from the input streams containing the spreadsheet and drt file which you can get from classpath.

To create *KieSession* with generated rules do the following:

```
ExternalSpreadsheetCompiler converter = new ExternalSpreadsheetCompiler();
String drl = converter.compile(spreadsheetStream, ruleTemplateStream, 1, 1);
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
kfs.write("src/main/resources/simple.drl", kieServices.getResources().newReaderResource(new StringReader(drl)));
KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kfs).buildAll();
KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieBuilder.getKieModule().getReleaseId());
KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
```

Comment: This works great! I spent like 8 hrs debugging this... Also to note that if I have read the XLS/DRT files into `byte[] file` arrays, I can create an InputStream with `new ByteArrayInputStream(file)` to feed the spreadsheet compiler.